# How to detect if a function parameter value was entered or it is the default value

Tags: kotlin, reflection

Having a function defined as

```
fun foo(
  bar: String? = null
) { ... }
```

how can be known if `bar` is `null` because no value was passed or because `null` was passed? I.e. the function was called as `foo()` or `foo(bar = null)`?

Actual case:

```
data class State(
  val foo: String? = null,
  val bar: Int? = null,
  val baz: Long? = null,
)

class StateManager {

  var state: State
    private set

  fun setState(
    foo: String? = null,
    bar: Int? = null,
    baz: Long? = null,
  ) {
    state = state.copy(foo, bar, baz)
  }
}
```

This example is not working, because `setState(bar = 1)` overrides with `null` `foo` and `baz` variables. `state.copy(bar = 1)` instead does not override `foo` and `baz`. I assume `copy`'s implementation is able to differentiate if `null` is provided as a parameter or if it is the default value.

The best I got:

```
  fun setState(
    val foo: String? = null,
    val bar: Int? = null,
    val baz: Long? = null,
  ) {
      val copyRef = state::copy
      val params = copyRef.parameters
      val values = mutableMapOf<KParameter, Any?>()
      if (foo != null) values[params[0]] = foo
      if (bar != null) values[params[1]] = bar
      if (baz != null) values[params[2]] = baz
      state = copyRef.callBy(values)
  }
```

This solution does not override with `null` unspecified values, but is not able to assign `null` when wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is not possible to detect if the param was not provided or default value was provided. `copy()` uses current member values as default values.

So I can achieve my goal with

```
class StateManager {

  var state: State
    private set

  fun setState(
    foo: String? = state.foo,
    bar: Int? = state.bar,
    baz: Long? = state.baz,
  ) {
    state = state.copy(foo, bar, baz)
  }
}
```

Thanks to Kotlin forum: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/solved-how-to-detect-if-a-function-parameter-value-was-entered-or-it-is-the-default-value/27764

Answer (score 2):

First, `val/var` is not allowed to be used before function parameters. I guess  they were copy-paste mistakes in your post.

I don't know your exact use case, but very likely, you can design it in a different way.

Focusing on the problem you described, how about **removing default values from all parameters of the `setState()` function?**

```
fun setState(foo: String?, bar:Int?, baz:Long?){
   state = State(foo, bar, baz) //or copy(...), if you love that way
}
```

When you call `setState()`, say, you want to use `bar` from the current `state`, and reset `foo` with a new value, and `baz` as `null`:

```
setState(newFoo, state.bar, null)
```

In this way, you read the values you don't want to touch from the current `state`, and pass them together with your new values to the function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I fixed the function params, thanks. In my current code State has a lot of members, passing all values to setState is not ideal.